# using std::thread in a library loaded with dlopen leads to a sigsev

Tags: c++, glibc, dlopen, stdthread

I recently discovered a strange behaviour using `std::thread` and `dlopen`.

Basically, when I execute a `std::thread` in a library which is loaded using `dlopen` I receive a sigsev. The library itself is linked against pthread, the executable that calls `dlopen` is not.

Once I link the executable against `pthread` or the library itself everything works fine. However, we are using a plugin based infrastructure, where we do not know if the application itself is linked against pthread or not. Therefore, it is not an option to link the executable always against pthread.

Please find attached some code to reproduce the Issue. Currently I am not sure what causes the Issue. Is it a problem of gcc, glibc, libstdc++, or the ld.so? Is there a convenient way to work around this? I looks like this [glibc bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16628) is related, but I am using glibc2.27 (debian testing).

Calling `pthread_create` itself from the library seems to work.

#### hello.cpp

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void thread()
{
    std::thread t ([](){std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;});
    t.join();
}

extern "C" {
    void hello()
    {
        thread();
    }
}
```

#### example.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

/** code from https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/
*/
int main() {

    std::cout << "C++ dlopen demo\n\n";

    // open the library
    std::cout << "Opening hello.so...\n";
    void* handle = dlopen("./libhello.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!handle) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open library: " << dlerror() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    // load the symbol
    std::cout << "Loading symbol hello...\n";
    typedef void (*hello_t)();

    // reset errors
    dlerror();
    hello_t hello = (hello_t) dlsym(handle, "hello");
    const char *dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if (dlsym_error) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot load symbol 'hello': " << dlsym_error <<
            '\n';
        dlclose(handle);
        return 1;
    }

    // use it to do the calculation
    std::cout << "Calling hello...\n";
    hello();

    // close the library
    std::cout << "Closing library...\n";
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

#### build.sh (build and execute the upper example. Example 1 crashes)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "g++ -shared -fPIC -std=c++14 hello.cpp -o libhello.so -pthread"
g++ -shared -fPIC -std=c++14 hello.cpp -o libhello.so -pthread

echo "g++ example.cpp -o example1 -ldl"
g++ example.cpp -o example1 -ldl

echo "g++ example.cpp -o example2 -ldl -pthread"
g++ example.cpp -o example2 -ldl -pthread

echo "g++ example.cpp -o example3 -ldl -lhello -L ./"
g++ example.cpp -o example3 -ldl -lhello -L ./

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$(pwd)

echo "===== example1 ====="
./example1
echo "===== end      ====="

echo "===== example2 ====="
./example2
echo "===== end      ====="

echo "===== example3 ====="
./example3
echo "===== end      ====="
```

### EDIT

I forgot to mention: If I am running the faulty example (i.e. example 1) using `LD_DEBUG=all` the program crashes during the lookup of `pthread_create`. Even more interesting is that a former lookup of `pthread_create` succeeds:

```
  8111:     symbol=_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
  8111:     binding file ./libhello.so [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=./example1 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=./libhello.so [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 [0]
  8111:     binding file ./libhello.so [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 [0]: normal symbol `pthread_create' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
  8111:     symbol=_ZTVNSt6thread6_StateE;  lookup in file=./example1 [0]
  8111:     symbol=_ZTVNSt6thread6_StateE;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
  8111:     symbol=_ZTVNSt6thread6_StateE;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
  8111:     binding file ./libhello.so [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZTVNSt6thread6_StateE' [GLIBCXX_3.4.22]
  ...
  8111:     binding file ./libhello.so [0] to ./libhello.so [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSt10_Head_baseILm0EPNSt6thread6_StateELb0EE7_M_headERS3_'
  8111:     symbol=_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE;  lookup in file=./example1 [0]
  8111:     symbol=_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
  8111:     symbol=_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
  8111:     binding file ./libhello.so [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE' [GLIBCXX_3.4.22]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=./example1 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
  8111:     symbol=pthread_create;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
  ./build.sh: line 18:  8111 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) LD_DEBUG=all ./example1
  ===== end      =====
```

Comment: I can reproduce the segmentation fault with glibc/libstdc++, but no segmentation fault with libc++.

Comment: _> it is not an option to link the executable always against pthread._ On the contrary, it is the only option. Don't worry, it will not have any negative consequence even if the plugin doesn't use threads.

Comment: > _On the contrary, it is the only option. Don't worry, it will not have any negative consequence even if the plugin doesn't use threads._

It's not about negative consequnences, we simply cannot make this assumption about the users application.

Comment: May be relevant https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16628

Comment: Have you checked that `/etc/ld.so.conf` contains the path of the `pthread` lib?

Comment: _It's not about negative consequnences, we simply cannot make this assumption about the users application._ The assumption I suggest is: 'the user's plugin either uses pthreads or not' If you build the main executable with pthreads, it will work in both cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can offer some background as to why there is a segfault, but unfortunately no solution.

It seems that this is an issue with `libstdc++`: Technically this huge monolithic library depends on `libpthread`, but for good reasons, they do not link against `libpthread`. Now in order to be able to load `libstdc++` from programs that don't use threads at all, the missing symbols (e.g. `pthread_create`) must come somewhere. So `libstdc++` defines them as weak symbols.

These weak symbols are also used to detect at runtime whether `libpthread` is actually loaded. For an old ABI there even was a [check in `_M_start_thread`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3d7527b1f7227a3bb539bf1e68b7ce7ba7205047/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/thread.cc#L147) which caused a meaningful exception if pthread was not loaded instead of calling a weakly defined `nullptr` - something I would not wish upon my worst enemey.

Unfortunately that run-time check got lost for the new ABI. Instead, there is a [link-time check](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3d7527b1f7227a3bb539bf1e68b7ce7ba7205047/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/thread#L126) for `pthread_create` by creating a dependency when compiling the code which calls `_M_start_thread`, and passing a pointer to `pthread_create` into this function. Unfortunately that pointer is discarded and the still weakly `nullptr` pointer is used.

Now something during the linking/loading causes the weakly defined `pthread_create` to not be overridden in your problematic case. I am unsure about the exact resolution rules that apply there - I assume it has to do with `libstdc++` being already fully loaded when `libpthread` is being loaded. I would be glad if any additional answer would clarify that. Unfortunately there also seems to be no generally viable option to fix that other than linking the main application with `-lpthread` or `LD_PRELOAD=libpthread.so` (which I wouldn't really recommend).

Comment: This needs to be filed as a bug against libstdc++. If it works in libc++, there's no reason why it shouldn't work in libstdc++.

Comment: It seems there is already a bug report for the libstdc++, which I hadn't found till now:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67791

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in libstdc++.

- With C programs this doesn't happen.
- With C++ programs built with libc++ this also doesn't happen.
- With C++ programs built with libstdc++ *statically* this also doesn't happen.
- With libraries build with libc++ this doesn't happen even if the caller program is built with libstdc++ dynamically.
- When the program dlopens the library with RTLD_GLOBAL, this also doesn't happen.

So one solution would be to switch to libc++. Obviously this only works if one never export any interface that relies on any `std::` type. In particular, a library that only exports C-compatible interfaces should be OK.

Another solution would be to have your library loaded with RTLD_GLOBAL (you may have to separate it in two, the main one and a small stub that just loads the main one with RTLD_GLOBAL).

In parallel one should file a bug against libstdc++ and wait for a fix. There's no reason why it should be broken like that.

If none of the above are viable options, then the only solution seems to involve a complete isolation between the caller and the multithreaded module. Make the multithreaded module a separate executable, fork-exec it from your plugin, marshal arguments/results to/from it via pipes.

Finally, there's always the ugly workaround of preloading libpthread in the caller program.

Comment: I wonder if libcapsule (https://gitlab.collabora.com/vivek/libcapsule/-/blob/master/doc/Strategy.txt) might be another solution?  Can you expand on your RTLD_GLOBAL / "small stub" idea?

Answer (score 4):

> Once I link the executable against pthread or the library itself everything works fine. However, we are using a plugin based infrastructure, where we do not know if the application itself is linked against pthread or not. Therefore, it is not an option to link the executable always against pthread.

On the *contrary*: very few systems support an application becoming "suddenly multithreaded" (your system obviously doesn't).

If you need to support *potentially* multithreaded plugin, then you must start out multithread-ready, which is achieved by linking against `libpthread`, or more portably by adding `-pthread` flag to compile and link lines for the main executable.

> Is it a problem of gcc, glibc, libstdc++, or the ld.so

It's a problem with `libstdc++` -- GLIBC does support "suddenly multithreaded" execution, GCC isn't part of the runtime environment at all, and `ld.so` is part of GLIBC.

Comment: > _It's a problem with libstdc++_
I am not compleatly sure about this. A collegue just pointed out that segementation fault occures during the ld search, you'll see using `LD_DEBUG=all`. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: Do you have any links / documentation regarding "suddenly multithreaded" support? My investigation indicates that this is related to a very specific hack in `libstdc++` (see my answer).