# Linux with GCC, after dlopen(), create thread failure for segment fault

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to design a library. To support different link type, I've tested static-link, dynamic-link directly and open sharing library. For the third way, it seems the code will failure on creating the thread after using `dlopen()` to open the library and get the address of the function with `dlsym()`. But the static-link and dynamic-link would be of no problem.

The main part of the function is:

```cpp
class test_t
{
    public:
        test_t(){}
        static test_t& get_instance()
        {
            static test_t t;
            return t;
        }

        void process()
        {
        }

        void detach()
        {
            auto t = std::thread([]{
                    auto& d = test_t::get_instance();
                    while(true)
                    {
                    d.process();
                    }
                    });
            std::cout << t.get_id() << std::endl;
            t.detach();
        }
    private:
};

extern "C" void init()
{
    test_t::get_instance().detach();
}
```

The call-stack case when segment fault is:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff79059a5 in std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff6c9dc4b in std::thread::thread<test_t::detach()::{lambda()#1}, , void>(test_t::detach()::{lambda()#1}&&) (this=0x7fffffffe150, __f=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/thread:131
#3  0x00007ffff6c9daf5 in test_t::detach (this=0x7ffff6ea0262 <test_t::get_instance()::t>) at /test/a.cpp:28
#4  0x00007ffff6c9d906 in init () at /test/a.cpp:37
#5  0x0000555555554ac0 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2a8) at /test/b.cpp:37
```

if the init function `init()` is invoked from a funcition pointer got by `dlsym()`, the runtime will raise an error of `segment fault`, but I cannot know which one is `nullptr`. The only place I could check is the c++'s standard `thread` header file, but I got no hint for why the runtime receives the `nullptr`. I wonder if it's the static member initialization issue, but got no clue.

The full test code with a CMakeLists.txt could be find [here](https://github.com/lanphon/test_thread_dlopen)

I've tested it with G++ 8.3.0, under Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Can't reproduce (Suse Linux + g++ 9.2.1).  Are you sure the library is found?  Your error handling simply prints a message and continues regardless.

Comment: you may set up the build directly inner the folder, since it would check the `liba.so` under the current working directory. To build it, just use "cmake .". If you build in a differnt directory, you can create a soft link for the `liba.so` unnder the binary `b`. `b` should find the `liba.so` just under the same folder.

Comment: When I say `"Can't reproduce"` I mean I can't reproduce the problem.  It builds and works as expected.

Comment: Yes. Seems it's GCC bug. I've tested GCC with version 7.4.0 and 8.4.0 on ubuntu, and the segment fault could be reproduced. After changing to clang-9, it could work normally. GCC 9 is too newer for me to get one. I'd like to find the root reason and check if there is way work around this bug.

Comment: It's a known problem of libstdc++, which is found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209268/using-stdthread-in-a-library-loaded-with-dlopen-leads-to-a-sigsev . Who can help me close this question??